# SIP VOIP звонок

Tags: python, sip, voip

Задача: 
Через  произвольно заданный SIP осуществлять звонок по номеру, и проигрывать заданный файл.

Если погуглить, то первое что встречается - [`MOST VOIP`](http://most-voip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_docs/tutorial/voip_tutorial_1.html) 
Но документация *мягко говоря* слабовата, да и версия далека до релиза.
Ищется библиотека помощнее, если у кого есть опыт - поделитесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте библиотеку PJSIP http://www.pjsip.org/ Написана на С++. Документация нормальная.
Есть модули и для Питона https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial